# ExecuteNonQueryAsync and commit in a SQL Transaction

Tags: c#, ado.net

I am after some help with a piece of code I have created, I am attempting to make an Async SQL call from c# within a transaction, for example I might be updating or deleting rows from a table.

This is what I have so far, but I cannot seem to find much information on doing this in a transaction, from what I have here and what I understand so far, I believe it may attempt to commit the transaction before the command has fully completed if the command is time-consuming.  If you could advise / point me to an example I would really appreciate it.

```
var sqlQuery = "delete from table";
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            await connection.OpenAsync();
            using (var tran = connection.BeginTransaction())
            {
                using (var command = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, connection, tran))
                {
                    await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                    tran.Commit();
                }
            }
        }
```

Thanks,

Comment: @Igor Thanks for the help, the method is actually called from a different class that is wrapped in a try catch - sorry I should of mentioned that in my post.

Comment: Good deal. You still need a reference to the created `SqlTransaction` though so you can execute `tran.RollBack()` in the code (see answer below), no sense in having the calling code do that unless this is a small sample from a larger database abstraction wrapper or something.

Comment: @Igor Good shout, thanks for your answer

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your code looks good. I just added a try/catch on the execution of the command so you can roll back your transaction if it fails. Because you are using the `await` keyword on the line `await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();` execution will block until the method returns regardless of how long it takes (unless you get a timeout exception from the command itself in which case you should set the command's execution timeout higher or figure out why its taking so long).

```
    var sqlQuery = "delete from table";
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        await connection.OpenAsync();
        using (var tran = connection.BeginTransaction())
        using (var command = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, connection, tran))
        {
            try {
                await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
            } catch {
                tran.Rollback();
                throw;
            }
            tran.Commit();
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is possible to get exception due command timeout in **tran.Commit()**