# Closing a SqlConnection does not close the close the transaction on SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, session, transactions, locking

We have a data access layer to an Azure database:

```
public async Task ExecuteStoredProcedure(string connectionName, string statementText, object parameters)
{
        using (var conn = GetConnection(connectionName))
        {
            await DataActions.ExecuteStoredProcedure(conn, this as IQueryTimeoutReader, statementText, parameters);
            conn.Close();
            conn.Dispose();
        }           
}


internal async static Task ExecuteStoredProcedure(SqlConnection connection, IQueryTimeoutReader timeoutReader, string statementText, object parameters) 
{
        var command = connection.CreateCommand();            
        command.CommandText = statementText;
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        if (timeoutReader != null)
        {
            command.CommandTimeout = timeoutReader.ReadAndResetTimeout();
        }

        ObjectToSqlParameters(parameters, command.Parameters);

        Stopwatch sw = SqlLogStart(connection, command);
        await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
        SqlLogStop(sw, 0);
}
```

I have a fairly straight forward query that I'm executing:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdatePartyAccessHistory]
    @UserID uniqueidentifier,
    @PartyID uniqueidentifier
AS
    IF (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM [PartyAccessHistory] 
        WHERE [UserID] = @UserID AND [PartyID] = @PartyID) = 0
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [PartyAccessHistory] ([PartyAccessHistoryID], [UserID], [PartyID], [LastAccessedDate])
            SELECT NEWID(), @UserID, @PartyID, GETDATE()
    END 
    ELSE
    BEGIN 
        UPDATE [PartyAccessHistory] 
        SET [LastAccessedDate] = GETDATE()
        WHERE [UserID] = @UserID AND [PartyID] = @PartyID
    END
```

The symptom I'm experiencing is this: the stored procedure shown above executes instantaneously, but then locks the table for several seconds.

I have the following query with which I query the database:

```
DECLARE @result TABLE 
                (
                    SPID INT,
                    [Status] VARCHAR(255),
                    Login VARCHAR(255),
                    HostName VARCHAR(255),
                    BlkBy VARCHAR(255),
                    DBName VARCHAR(255),
                    Command VARCHAR(255),
                    CPUTime INT,
                    DiskIO INT,
                    LastBatch VARCHAR(255),
                    ProgramName VARCHAR(255),
                    SPID2 INT,
                    REQUESTID INT
                )

INSERT INTO @result EXEC sp_who2
    SELECT Result.*, [text], Transactions.open_tran 
    FROM @result AS Result
    LEFT JOIN sys.dm_exec_requests der ON der.session_id = Result.SPID 
    OUTER APPLY SYS.dm_exec_sql_text (der.sql_handle) Sql 
    OUTER APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan (der.plan_handle) pln 
    LEFT JOIN sys.objects so ON so.object_id = sql.objectid 
    LEFT JOIN sys.sysprocesses AS Transactions ON Transactions.SPID = Result.SPID 

    -- Add any filtering of the results here :
    WHERE ProgramName = 'CRM-Program'  
      AND DBName = 'CRM'
```

It returns a list of current sessions, which sessions is blocked by which sessions, and which sessions have open transactions associated with them.

It turns out, if I run a different update statement, it is blocked by the session that ran the above stored procedure. But that session completed already, and is sleeping. Yet, the sleeping session still have the active transaction that's locking the tables.

I understand that we're doing connection pooling, to reuse connections, but to my mind, a sleeping session should never have an open transaction associated with it: The transaction must be committed before the the session sleep. (Ok, maybe not always, but in this instance, I DEFINITELY do not want any active transactions remaining on the session after I executed this stored procedure).

However, no matter what I do, it either introduces new errors or it doesn't work.
I tried to get the transaction from the connection and manually commit it, but that gave me an error message which apparently only two people in the world ever received:

> BeginExecuteNonQuery requires the command to have a transaction when the connection assigned to the command is in a pending local transaction.  The Transaction property of the command has not been initialized

Explicitly calling close and dispose on the connection doesn't close the transaction either.

A colleague of mine says that the solution is that I should refactor my code to do fewer calls to the database, and while he might have a point, I still think it is treating the symptom rather than the root cause: There should be a way to close the transaction on the session once you're done.

Please, anyone, how do I force the open transaction to close on the SQL Server session once the stored procedurewas executed?

Comment: Could you use command.ExecuteNonQuery() without the await and the async? Maybe that does the trick.

Comment: Probably not the cause, but you're not disposing of your SqlCommand object

Comment: Not really. This is an API, and everything needs to be async. Even if you could convince me, the rest of the team would not bite.

Comment: Also, you're passing the connection and command to `SqlLogStart` - what's in that and what's in `SqlLogStop`?

Comment: This may be useful: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/41709/sleeping-spid-blocking-other-transactions and perhaps this: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/188262/identifying-why-query-is-sleeping-with-open-transactions

Comment: Do you have implicit transactions enabled?

Comment: @Alex.

When checking my SqlConnection object, TransactionBinding = ImplicitUnbind
PoolBlockingPeriod = Auto

I've looked at your other links. I've tried using  SET XACT_ABORT ON, but it had no effect. The other suggestion of having a dedicated service killing sleeping sessions with open transactions might be a hard sell to the rest of the team. Thanks for your input though. I'm still looking through those to see if there's anything else in them.

Comment: @Stuartd

Those are just logging debugging info, recording what's being executed and how long it took. They don't really affect anything.

Comment: RE "Those are just logging debugging info" - does it log to DB table?

Comment: I've implimented this code in my DAL:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36040111/executenonqueryasync-and-commit-in-a-sql-transaction

I added the code to manually create and commit the transaction, and although it works perfectly in the API, when I run the query above, the transaction remain open on the sleeping session. UGH!

Comment: @Alex. No, it just print it to the debugging output window in Visual Studio.

Comment: I am out of ideas. If this happens to only one SP, then the issue is likely SP/table specific: check triggers on this table for failure conditions; re-index the table; update statistics (this will eliminate any corruption possibilities)). If this affects more than this table then the issue is with your API most likely. Good luck and let us know how you solve this. Ensure that command timeout is not too short.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone's help so far.

The thing is, the application makes a call to the API to update the table, and then immediately makes another call to select from that same table - joined to other tables. My colleague's theory is that this is what is causing the lock. He thinks the select is executed in the same transaction as the update (Which doesn't make sense to me, as that happens on a different thread) and that is what then locks the tables (Which also doesn't make sense to me, because even if the select statement runs on the same transaction as the update - both execute successfully, so there is no reason why the transaction should remain open and keep locking the tables)

Anyway - we'll be refactoring the code. He wants us to call the select sp only once during startup, and then maintain the list on client side instead of selecting it from the DB every time. That will not be without its own challenges, but hopefully this will resolve the issue. Ofcause, I still think its only treating the symptom without actually understanding the root cause, but at this stage I've tried every possible way I could think of to gain control over the transaction and close it, and nothing worked.